# Are their negatives to using the content type hub approach

Tags: content-type-hub

What are the pitfalls of using the content type hub approach to store global level content types?

Comment: Is there anything specific you wanted to know?

Comment: Particulars around management via feature.  Answer below touches on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can still utilize content types in addition to hubs, I don't think it is fair to list these as pitfalls, but maybe slight limitations.

- Workflows are not supported at the HUB (WF can be attached to list/library where content types are utilized)
- Content Types deployed as features to the HUB require the same
  feature be activated on sites utilizing those content types.

My exposure to CTH is limited, so there may be workarounds available for these.  A quick google searched turned up this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/02/09/content-type-hub-limitations.aspx), listing the above and a few more.